# Netbeans .properties : Where to put file referenced by "classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties"

Tags: java, spring, netbeans

So I'm trying to run an example here [Spring MVC and Spring JDBC Transaction Tutorial](http://o7planning.org/en/10311/spring-mvc-and-spring-jdbc-transaction-tutorial#a4791708.)

According to the article the location for **Eclipse** is here :

[image]

So I did it also in **Netbeans** :

[image]

But it gave me errors :

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: org.o7planning.springmvcjdbc.config.ApplicationContextConfig; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ds/datasource-cfg.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

and

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ds/datasource-cfg.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
```

I've been reading some post on SO about `.properties` resource accessing in netbeans but nothing seems work. The errors are only coming from those (accessing parts). The codes are overall just fine.

The "**classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties**" is declared in the following class. `ApplicationContextConfig.java`

```
package org.o7planning.springmvcjdbc.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.o7planning.springmvcjdbc.*")

@EnableTransactionManagement

// HERE ..!!!
// Load to Environment.
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties") })

public class ApplicationContextConfig {

   // The Environment class serves as the property holder
   // and stores all the properties loaded by the @PropertySource
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
   public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

       viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
       viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

       return viewResolver;
   }

   @Bean(name = "dataSource")
   public DataSource getDataSource() {
       DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

       // See: datasouce-cfg.properties
       dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("ds.database-driver"));
       dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ds.url"));
       dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("ds.username"));
       dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("ds.password"));

       System.out.println("## getDataSource: " + dataSource);

       return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
   public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
       DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();

       DataSource dataSource = this.getDataSource();
       txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

       return txManager;
   } 
}
```

So where to put this `resources` folder in netbeans ?

Comment: Add a slash before ds

Comment: Hi @Jens, same errors , why is it so hard accessing things in netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it :

I comment this :

```
//@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:ds/datasource-cfg.properties") })
```

Then I add this

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {  
         registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

In the class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`